# Catch R Selenium error message and write it to log

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I have a few scrapes via RSelenium scheduled. Sometimes the scraping failes and i would like to know the reason. 
I note that the error Messages (in red) are quite informative, but i dont know how to log them.

Lets say i provided a "non well formed URL".:

```
tryCatch(
  expr = remDr$navigate("i.am.not.an.url"),
  error = function(error){
    print(error)
    # write.table(error, file = ...)
  }  
)
```

**This is what i get, but it doesnt give much specification on what triggered the error**

```
<simpleError:    Summary: UnknownError
Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
Further Details: run errorDetails method>
```

**This is more informative - but i dont manage to log it.**

```
Selenium message:Target URL i.am.not.an.url is not well-formed.
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: '9bc48e7a4511', ip: '172.17.0.4', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-1087-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

**What i tried:**

Using the Error Handling Class. It includes very detailed specification of the error Messages and its meanings, but i dont manage to extract them given my current error.

```
errHandle = errorHandler(remDr)
errHandle$checkStatus(remDr)
errHandle$checkError(res = remDr)
```

Using a message handler from another #SO question:

```
messageHandler <- function(fun, ...) {
  zz <- textConnection("foo", "w", local = TRUE)
  sink(zz, type = "message")
  res <- fun(...)  
  sink(type = "message")
  close(zz)
  #handle messages
  list(res, messages = foo) 
}

wrongURL <- function() {
  remDr$navigate("mistake")
}

messageHandler(fun = wrongURL)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a way via `errorDetails()`:

```
tryCatch(
  expr = remDr$navigate("i.am.not.an.url"),
  error = function(error){
    return(remDr$errorDetails()$localizedMessage)
  }  
)
```